# Is JHipster meant to be used as the backbone for any java web application?

Tags: jhipster

Our team is planning to create an eLearning application. 
The technology stack we plan to use is exactly the one used by jHipster and we can see some evident benefits in using jHipster:

- it will force our code to be well structured
- when we add a new entity most of code generated could be used as is, with the exception of the html itself

However the interface will be very different from the default interface and some of the functionnalities are far from CRUD (more game like)

My questions are:

- can jHipster be used for an app that is not 100% CRUD ?
- when using jHipster is the idea to replace the html by our own views while keeping most of the generated code as is ?
- is there any live website build with jHipster that are not just cosmetic tweaks of the default views ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe JHipster can be used for applications that aren't all CRUD. The monitoring, user management and admin features can be useful. The development experience with BrowserSync is also very nice. Even if you don't use JHipster, you can certainly generate an application and learn from its code.

I've built a couple applications that aren't 100% CRUD. The only problem with customizing a JHipster app too much is it makes it hard to upgrade. However, you can upgrade the dependencies yourself or just create new files instead of modifying existing ones.

Here's a couple sites I've built:

- http://www.jhipster-book.com
- http://www.21-points.com

Comment: is this some ready css in that 21-points.com or have you implemented one of your own? I really like that style.

Comment: Thanks Matt. What I understand is that jHipster CAN be used for non CRUD applications, but is not really MEANT to be used this way... I have checked your two sites and it seems to me that they still seem quite close to the defaut jHipster app. I think I will follow your second suggestion and just learn from jHipster's code...

Comment: @Sami The theme is Material Design for Bootstrap: https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/

Comment: @BenL (reply to my own self of the past) : we are actually using jHipster now and we found out that it was very easy to change / remove any of the technology. jHipster is GREAT to build a CRUD application out of the box within hours, and it is also an excellent FRAME for a NON CRUD application, even with a complex business logic. I went to a jHipster meet up yesterday and met 30+ users of jHipster who could confirm that.  jHipster is also an excellent way to learn how to use all the technologies of its stack using best practices.

Answer (score 0):

We are using J-Hipster as non-crud application.

in one specific application, we are using J-Hipster without any front-end ! We are only using the DB acces, the application running on a server (embedded), some Rest command...

J-Hipster may be not the best tool for that, but it helps you to have an opperationnal build in less than a week (less than 2 days in fact). We didn't have to search for some logger, to search wich DB was the best...